# VisualStudio copies all dlls to output directory

Tags: visual-studio

I noticed recently that VisualStudio started to copy literally *all* my referenced assemblies and much more into the build directory.

The system namespace takes up ~100 Files in my output directory, which is very annoying (e.g. 11x System.IO.XXX, 10x System.Diagnostics.XXX, 11x System.Net.XXX etc...). No other GAC-Namespaces seem to be affected, though.

I do not have any post-build actions set up, neither for the Debug- or Release-Configuration. Heck, I don't even reference all of them in my project (only 7 System-related References) and all of them are set to not be copied into my output directory except System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow because it's from NuGet, but changing that one does not make any difference.

The project also doesn't reference any other project in that solution which *could maybe* explain that behaviour but uses some (10) NuGet-Packages.

Where can I start to look to find out why VS deems it necessary to polute my build directory with all this junk? Because the program runs just fine when I remove all those unnecessary files.

**Edit:**
Project was a normal .NET 4.7 project. Upgrading it to 4.7.1 as a comment suggested did help to cut down the clutter from 100 files to about 13. Any way to get rid of those 13 files?

Comment: Is it a .NET Core project by any chance?

Comment: Tends to happen for Nuget packages that were updated to target .NETStandard.  Either change the project's target framework version to at least 4.7.1 (VS2017 implied) or use an older version of the package.

Comment: it is not a core project, just 4.7. Updating it to 4.7.1  did cut down the clutter to 13 unnecessary references - Looks like Tasks.Dataflow is indeed a .NETStandard library. Any way to get rid of those remaining 13 ones? If not that comment is basically the complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props
TrimmerRootAssembly section or more common as thought
UseAppHost and set it to False. For me it removed all System.* dlls from output

Comment: Direct link to TrimmerRootAssembly section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#trimmerrootassembly

Answer (score 0):

Same behaviour is seen when upgrading from net40 to net472 using the dotnet upgrade tool. Targeting net7-windows (the upgrade tool's chouce) works fine. Changing target framework to net472 results in same issue as described above.

Adding the following to the SDK project file helps :

```
<PropertyGroup>
    ...
    CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>false</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score -1):

On the References Properties , We need to set the Copy Local property to false if you dont want to copy to the local directory

Comment: Yes . If there is a reference which is referencing these dlls , then will also be copied

Comment: That might be the case (Tasks.Dataflow is the source) but I need that one copied but all the other stuff alongside is already registered in the GAC and part of .NET and should not be copied to the output directory (as they are already part of .NET), not even if they are referenced by Tasks.Dataflow.

Comment: Btw. disabling Copy local on the source reference did not have any effect.

Comment: Can you try by performing a CleanBuild operation and then rebuild