# Are all System.*.dll required in the output folder?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

My WPF application is using the old csproj way (not SDK style) and targets the `.NET Framework 4.6.1`. But I converted it to `PackageReference`.

Here are some examples of the referenced Nuget packages:

- Microsoft.BclAsyncInterfaces
- RestSharp
- System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF
- etc

When I build my application, the bin folder contains:

- the dlls produced by my application
- some `Microsoft.*.dll`
- the `RestSharp` dlls

But also a lots of `System.*.dll` (more than 100 O_o).

Among them, there is `System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF` which I believe is required because it is not part of the .NET Framework.

But there also is a lots of dll that are parts of the .NET Framework:

- `System.Collections.dll`
- `System.Linq.dll`
- etc

I guess all these dll are here because some of the referenced packages are using them. But are they all really necessary? I mean, I am targeting the `.NET Framework`, not `.NET core`, so why all these "native" dll are copied to my output folder?

I am asking this because I am building the setup of my application. I could obviously add all the dlls in the output folder into the setup but I would rather avoid it if possible.

If they are not all required, how can I decide which dll I have to add to the setup and which I can omit?

Comment: Most likely you have used a nuget package that requires the .net standard assemblies, I don't know what the terminology is for those, shim? interface?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that at least one of the referenced package is a .NET Standard library (but probably the `Microsoft.BclAsyncInterfaces` is too). So you are telling me that those `System.*.dll` are .net standard version of the native dll?

Comment: Not versions, but something in between. .NET Standard can work with both .NET Core and .NET Framework, and so they don't actually contain the actual implementation. Instead they contain a common compilation target, that will then wrap around the actual framework you're using, or sit between your application and that framework. I don't know enough about the actual way they implemented this, I just know that those dll's are required to make .NET standard work. So yes, you need those. Whether you need *all* of them, that I don't know, but I would think that you probably just leave them alone.

Comment: That makes sense. I think it worth a proper answer !

Comment: I don't, as I said I don't know enough about this to even know the terminology. If anyone knows enough about this topic to warrant an answer, please take whatever you want from my comment and post it as your own.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments in Stack Overflow question ([VisualStudio copies all dlls to output directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51102897/visualstudio-copies-all-dlls-to-output-directory) )  and information found on GitHub ([Targeting .NET Framework 4.7.1 copies extra files to your bin directory](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net471/KnownIssues/514195-Targeting%20.NET%20Framework%204.7.1%20copies%20extra%20files%20to%20your%20bin%20directory.md)). I believe this issue may be related to your target framework version of 4.6.1. Updating your target framework 4.7.2 should remove the system DLLs from your output directory.